# printing image using window.print() in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

          $('#pdf').click(function(){
               printDiv();
               function printDiv() {
                    var printContents = $(".right_content").text();
                    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
                    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
                    window.print();
                    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
               }
          });
      });
</script>
```

This is my html code:

```
<div class="right_content">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url()."images/12masi.png";?>" alt="12masi" 
          title="image"/>
</div>
```

This is my button:

```
<input type='submit'  value='Generate PDF' id="pdf"/>
```

Problem is that Image is not displaying in print-preview.I m using google chrome.
Is this a browser issue or something else??

Comment: Anyone tried this????

Comment: Have you tried `$(".right_content").html();`instead?

Comment: it's working..thnks...

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer. Please check it as having solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.html()` instead:

```
$(".right_content").html();
```